# What's the Meaning of the Aphorism "Contemporaries live from second hand to mouth"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

What's the meaning of the following aphorism by Karl Kraus:

> Contemporaries live from second hand to mouth.

Source: Half-Truths and One-and-a-Half Truths

Just to clarify, I know the meaning of "to live from hand to mouth" and "second hand", and the way I understand it is this, "Contemporaries live in subsistence of hearsay." Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Hello, Tayyab. The expression is a witticism that doesn't stand up to rigorous scrutiny.

Comment: I can't guess whether the allusion is to **second hand** = *used / recycled / hand-me-down* or **second hand** = *short-lived / ephemeral* (from the sweep second hand on analogue watches). It's a bit irrelevant whether anyone else already *knows* the answer to that, since it's not inherently fixed by the words themselves.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I do understand it's a witticism and wordplay but we can't overlook the meaning or overall sense of the aphorism.

Comment: It's a mixed metaphor, combining "second-hand" with "hand-to-mouth". It's not a standard saying, the author came up with it.

Comment: What does hearsay have to do with this? I think you don't really understand what "hand-to-mouth" means.

Comment: Karl Kraus was an Austrian, this is a translation from the German “Zeitgenossen leben aus zweiter Hand in den Mund”.

Comment: @Barmar Hearsay is second-hand conversation. A compulsive gossip might also be said to be living second-hand to mouth. Though I don’t believe this is the meaning here.

Comment: @NeilW Oh, that's would be a clever construction. It might even be intended if "half-truths" refers to things like gossip.

Answer (score 4):

This is combining two phrases that are associated with poor people.

Poor people can't afford to buy new clothes and other items, so they get things from friends and relatives, or they go to thrift shops. [*secondhand*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/secondhand) is a term for items that have been previously used by other people.

Living [*hand-to-mouth*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/secondhand) means a subsistence living, which is also a description of the life of very poor people.

The author is mixing these two metaphors to emphasize how poor these people are. They just barely get by, even though they're only buying preused items.

Comment: A convincing explanation of a rather arch piece of word-play by Kraus. I used to use a similar construct in French, but few people got it: “Il fait beaujourd’hui”.